# Undefined reference to function "CashRegister::GetTotalPrice"

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm trying to call a few functions in a separate class like so;

```
CashRegister* reg = new CashRegister();
 Subtotal = reg->GetTotalPrice(Shelf[Choice], Quantity);
            Tax = reg->GetTax(Subtotal);
            totalCost = Subtotal + Tax;
            cout << endl << "Aaah, big spender I see. That's going to cost you..." << endl;
            cout << "Subtotal: " << totalCost << endl << "Sales Tax: " << Tax << endl << "Total" << totalCost << endl;
```

But I'm getting the error "undefined reference to `CashRegister::GetTotalPrice(InventoryItem, int)` along with the same errors for the other calls.

Here's CashRegister.h

```
    #ifndef CASHREGISTER_H_INCLUDED
    #define CASHREGISTER_H_INCLUDED
    #include <string>
    #include "InventoryItem.h"
    using namespace std;

    //Constant variables
        const int PROFIT = .3;
        const int SALES_TAX = .06;
    class CashRegister
    {
        public:
        CashRegister();

        ~CashRegister();

        double GetTotalPrice(InventoryItem myItem, int numPurchased); //Gets the total price and returns it (INC. profit).
        double GetTax(double price); //Calculates sales tax and returns it (JUST the tax)
        double GetProfit(double price); //Adds the profit margin to the item and returns the value
    };


#endif // CASHREGISTER_H_INCLUDED
```

I can post the rest if you need it, but its a lot. I would very much appreciate any help!

edit: CashRegister.cpp;

```
#include "CashRegister.h"

CashRegister::CashRegister()
{

}

// Destructor
CashRegister::~CashRegister()
{

}
double GetProfit(double price)
{
    price = price * PROFIT;
    return price;
}

double GetTax(double price)
{
    price = price * SALES_TAX;
    return price;
}

double GetTotalPrice(InventoryItem myItem, double numPurchased)
{
    double myPrice = myItem.getCost();
    myPrice = myPrice * numPurchased;
    myPrice = GetProfit(myPrice);
    return myPrice;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `.cpp` file as well, please?

Comment: Unrelated: Never do `using namespace std;` into the global namespace in header files. It'll taint the global namespace for all users of your header with possible errors/unexpected happenings as a result.

Comment: Out of curiousity: `double numPurchased` implies buying non-integer amounts. Is that on purpose?

Comment: No, it's not. I'll fix that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header:

```
double GetTotalPrice(InventoryItem myItem, int numPurchased)
```

Your `.cpp`:

```
double GetTotalPrice(InventoryItem myItem, double numPurchased)
```

The signature of the function in the `.cpp` file does not match that of the function in your header file. The function in the `.cpp` file is also a free function, not part of the class.

You need this in your `.cpp`:

```
double CashRegister::GetTotalPrice(InventoryItem myItem, int numPurchased) {
//...
}
```

The same goes for the other member functions you've declared in the header file. Add `CashRegister::` before the function name in the `.cpp` file.